# How to open Postman test run results from exported file

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I exported the Postman collection test result manually.
How to open it? I keep getting the error "Failed to import..." when I try to open it with File->Import.
Although when I select the file it is recognized as postman collection run.
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate? What is the file you are trying to import, what other factors are involved? The more related information you give. The better you help us help you :)